# Ударение в слове "трапезничать"

Tags: фонетика

ТрАпеза, трАпезная. А какое ударение будет в слове "трапезничать"? По логике - "трАпезничать", но вспомним знаменитую фразу из "Ивана Васильевича": "Царь трапЕзничать желает!"
Так, как же правильно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Слово трАпеза заимствовано из греческого языка (стол, кушанье) и сохраняет ударение первоисточника.

Однако норма произношения этого слова долгое время была неустойчивой, например:"За трАпезой гость пречудный" (Н.Клюев).  "Враги! Давно ли друг от друга Их жажда крови отвела? Давно ль они часы досуга, ТрапЕзу, мысли и дела Делили дружно?" (А. Пушкин).

Современные орфоэпические словари предлагают форму "трапЕзовать", слова "трапезничать" в них нет. Из толкового словаря: ТрапЕзничать. Есть, принимать пищу (в монастыре). / Шутл. Гости трапЕзничали до поздней ночи. Трапезничали всегда на веранде.

Следует отметить, что в процессе словообразования (например, трАпеза - трапЕзничать) ударение может меняться, так как выбирается удобная фонетическая форма для нового слова.